# How can I open a named pipe?

Tags: php, file-io, named-pipes

- Ubuntu 9.10 / CentOS 5.5
- PHP 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.7 / 5.2.11

The following minimal testcase gives this output:

> string(3) "foo"
>
> Warning: stat() [function.stat]: stat failed for Resource id #3 in /[...]/mkfifo.php on line 10
>
> bool(false)

```
<?php

$pipe_name = 'foo';
if(!file_exists($pipe_name) && !posix_mkfifo($pipe_name, 0777)){
  echo 'foo';
  exit(1);
}
var_dump($pipe_name);
$pipe = fopen($pipe_name, 'r+');
var_dump(stat($pipe));

?>
```

Surely I'm doing something wrong?  I used r+ because it's supposedly "works for me" per http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-mkfifo.php#89642 but as you can see I don't even get a chance to do the non-blocking part.  Alternative, more verbose solution that I haven't tried yet: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#52826

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your error is soleley caused by using [`stat()`](http://php.net/stat) there. You give it an opened file resource, but it should be used with a `$filename` only.

Your pipe was correctly opened as evidenced by `Resource id #3`

Use `stat($pipe_name)` to get informations about the fifo.
Or `stream_get_meta_data($pipe)` for the opened file handle.